# Python/Jupyter: scroll scatter-plot with many data points horizontally

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, scatter-plot, line-plot

I want to visualize time-series-like data with several measurements over time.

There are a lot of such measurements in a dataset, in the order of tens to hundreds of thousands.

In order to view these in a notebook or HTML page, I would like some efficient method to show a subrange of the whole time range with just a view hundred to thousand database and have controls to scroll lef/right i.e. forward/backward in time through the data.

I have tried doing this with Plotly and a range slider, but unfortunately this does not scale to a lot of data at all. Apparently, this approach creates all the graph data in the output javascript, which slows down everything and at some point makes the browser hang or crash.

What I would need is an approach that actually only renders the data in the subrange and interacts with the python code via the scrolling widgets to update the view.

Ideally, this would work with Plotly as I am using it for all other visualizations, but any other efficient solution would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly runs into rendering issues when there are too many data points within the window (see [Plotly Benchmarks](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eplotly.js/133.embed)). I would suggest using [Plotly-Resampler](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler) which resamples data that is within the user's view.

Comment: Yes, I have discovered and tested this in the meantime as well. I have problems getting exceptions sometimes and also it is a bit clumsy to use as it lacks the one thing I would like: a scrollbar - I think it would be a better UI if one could set a window span first and then use a scrollbar to navigate through the time series, adapting the window size if needed.

Comment: As it turns out, there is nothing that would work like a scrollbar (only zooming), and the range-slider does not work properly with plotly-resampler, so it is not really a solution right now.

Comment: @jpp1 do you have a reproducible example of data and a figure?

Comment: It is possible to directly interact with the plytly example code demonstrating the range slider here: https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/

Comment: Would doing something like running the same plotly range slider (as you referenced above) with a ton of data be sufficient to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Yes - imagine having 100K or even 10M datapoints in the graph - the range slider is not a good way to browse through that graph. It is clumsy, and if the window we want to use is a small fraction of the whol slider bar, it is impossible to drag it for scrolling (as one will always click the boundary markers and change the size instead). 
So I was looking for an alternate way of scrolling the data